# Trouble importing yahoo finance to python

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I have installed yahoo finance from the PyPI with pip, and when I go to run the following script i get an import error: No module named yahoo_finance

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

BlackDiamond = Share('BDE')
print(BlackDiamond.get_open)
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? Perhaps pip is associated with the wrong one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `pip` installed to somewhere in Python's include path. Run this command:

```
$ pip show yahoo-finance
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: yahoo-finance
Version: 1.2.1
Summary: Python module to get stock data from Yahoo! Finance
Home-page: https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance
Author: Lukasz Banasiak
Author-email: lukasz@banasiak.me
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: pytz, simplejson
Entry-points:
  [console_scripts]
  yahoo-finance = yahoo_finance:main
```

See where it says `Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`? Make sure yours is the system site-packages directory. Often (for example, on Mac or Ubuntu) you need to `sudo pip install` to get them in system site-packages. If your intention is to install it as a user to somewhere in your home directory, you need to ensure that directory is in your python-path.

To see your current path settings, create a file called `path.py` in your home directory and include the following:

```
import os
import sys

try:
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
except KeyError:
    user_paths = []

print "PYTHONPATH: ", user_paths
print "sys.path: ", sys.path
```

Run `python path.py` and you should see output similar to this:

```
$ python path.py
PYTHONPATH:  ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '']
sys.path:  ['/Users/me/dir', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/..../lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Now, make sure the path where `yahoo_finance` was installed is inside your path configuration. If it's not, you can modify `$PYTHONPATH` via your `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/dir"
```

For example:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/dir"
$ python path.py
PYTHONPATH:  ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '', '/path/to/your/dir']
```

Then, you should be able to include your module. Again, though: If you're installing a system-wide site package, you probably just want to use `sudo pip`.

Comment: Thanks Will that was the issue!

Comment: Awesome, no problem :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me:    export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

Answer (score 0):

as a Windows user I couldn't quite follow Will's answer. Fortunetaly I came across a PYTHONPATH manager directly from my IDE (Spyder 5) and added the path in which the moduled was installed.

Altough the problem was solved, I still can't get mny head around the issue. The installation process was the same as for every other package I ever used, but in this case the path wasn't recognized, a common directory with the rest of my installed modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).