# Python yahoo-finance package ImportError: cannot import name Share

Tags: python

I am using Python2.7 and I try to use python yahoo-finance package on mac to get some data

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
print yahoo.get_open()
```

but it shows error message:
"ImportError: cannot import name Share"

I use sudo pip install to install yahoo-finance and below is the pip 
install info:

```
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: yahoo-finance
Version: 1.2.1
Summary: Python module to get stock data from Yahoo! Finance
Home-page: https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance
Author: Lukasz Banasiak
Author-email: lukasz@banasiak.me
Installer: pip
License: MIT
Location: /Users/Singsing/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: pytz, simplejson
```

I look up and try the code in this link:[Trouble importing yahoo finance to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357140/trouble-importing-yahoo-finance-to-python)

```
import os
import sys

try:
    user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
except KeyError:
    user_paths = []

print "PYTHONPATH: ", user_paths
print "sys.path: ", sys.path
```

My PythonPath is [] as result, I also try

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages" which is my pip install location but it doesn't work either.

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Requires: pytz, simplejson`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]
If you chekc pypi, you will see people usually use pandas to read data directly:
following links is documentation of how to read data from yahoo finance/google finance through pandas:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/remote_data.html?highlight=yahoo

You can get more data than you expected~